# bash: delete filles matching specific pattern if they are present in the directory

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to check the presence of the all filles started from the pattern in workdir and then to remove all of them if they are exist:

```
target='file_pattern_to_be_removed'
if [ -e "${workdir}"/${target}*.dat ]; then rm "${workdir}"/${target}*.dat; fi
```

which produces

```
./test.sh: line 482: [: too many arguments
```

Assuming that in the workdir there are totally 10 filles started form the pattern how would be better to execute such condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ -e ... ]` can't handle multiple parameters, but you don't actually have to check: with

```bash
shopt -s nullglob
rm -f "$workdir/$target"*.dat
```

you delete files if there are matches, and nothing happens if there is no match. The `nullglob` shell option is set so the glob expands to the empty string if nothing matches (else it would try to delete a file containing a literal `*`), and the `-f` option suppresses a warning about missing files if there was nothing to delete.

Comment: should I deactivate nullglob after the rm -f assuming that I run some pipeline after the cleaning of old data to produce new one

Comment: It's often a good setting to have, as you rarely rely on a non-matching glob being used literally. You can check the rest of the script for usage of globs and see if you expect that behaviour or not.